# Saving a PDF version of a Website created with Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, pdf, zurb-foundation

I created a web page for my CV using Zurb Foundation. It looks OK. I would like to to save a PDF version of the page so that I can offer it as a download on my site. However when I try to print and ASave as a PDF on OSX I get a cut down version.

What simple way can I get the screen version to be the print version so that I can save it as an identical PDF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this with the following in my `_settings.scss` file

```
$include-print-styles: false;
$small-screen: emCalc(768px);
$small: "print, screen and (min-width:"#{$small-screen}")";
```